# Is this statement about field extensions true or false?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> Let $F$ be a field. $[F(a) : F] = 4$ and $[F(b) : F] = 6$ implies $[F(a,b) : F] = 24.$

The statement is true or false. I think false but I did not give a counter example.

$$Q[\mathbb{^4\sqrt{2}}:{^6\sqrt2}]=[Q(^4\sqrt{2},^6\sqrt{2}):Q(^4\sqrt2][Q(^4\sqrt{2}):Q]$$
$$ [Q(^4\sqrt{2},\sqrt[6]{2}):Q(^4\sqrt2]=6$$
$$ 
 [Q(^4\sqrt{2}):Q]=4 $$
$$Q[\mathbb{^4\sqrt{2}}:{\sqrt[6]{2}}]=24 $$
$$ \;am\; i\; right? $$

Comment: Hint: we know that both $4$ and $6$ are factors of $[F(a, b) : F]$, so we know that $12$ is a factor. So the value could either be 24 or 12. See if you can find a case where it's 12.

Comment: The extension $ \mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}, 2^{1/6})$ has degree $12$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. A way to see that is to define $\mathbb{L}=\mathbb{Q}(2^{12})$, and to see that $[\mathbb{K} : \mathbb{Q} ] \geq 12$, that $[\mathbb{L} : \mathbb{Q}] =12$ and $\mathbb{K} \subset \mathbb{L}$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe thank you for your opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :**

$$\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{Q} \quad \quad \quad a=2^{1/4}  \quad \quad \quad \quad\quad\quad b=2^{1/6}$$